# can we use DML commands in sql functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im curious to know can we use DML commands like insert/update/delete in functions in sql server.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying?

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are two *separate* RDBMS products. Pick *one*.

Comment: Its Microsoft sql server

Comment: @DhivyaManivannan, since you are using Microsoft SQL Server, I removed the mysql tag. MySQL is an entirely different DBMS product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Micosoft SQL Server, functions [cannot produce side-effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql). This means you cannot modify the database state (change data available outside the function scope) within the function although you can execute `SELECT` DML. Below is an example script that illustrates this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(SomeData int IDENTITY);
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.BadFunction(@SomeData int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test (SomeData) VALUES(@SomeData);
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
GO
```

The function will not be created due to this error:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure BadFunction, Line 6 [Batch
>   Start Line 4] Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within
>   a function.

The function create will succeed if one uses a table variable instead of a regular table because the scope of the table variable is limited to within the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GoodFunction(@SomeData int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE(ID int IDENTITY, SomeData int);
    INSERT INTO @TableVariable (SomeData) VALUES(@SomeData);
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: **Yes**

And if you are more interested, you can read the following the following article :
[CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#interoperability)

And if you are feeling lazy, here is a snippet from that article:

> The following statements are valid in a function:
>
> - Assignment statements.
> - Control-of-Flow statements except TRY...CATCH statements.
> - DECLARE statements defining local data variables and local cursors.
> - SELECT statements that contain select lists with expressions that assign values to local variables.
> - Cursor operations referencing local cursors that are declared, opened, closed, and deallocated in the function. Only FETCH statements
>     that assign values to local variables using the INTO clause are
>     allowed; FETCH statements that return data to the client are not
>     allowed.
> - INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements modifying local table variables.
> - EXECUTE statements calling extended stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishesh answer is very misleading and it should be noted to readers that the commands can only be used in a local scope of temporary or variable tables. For general purpose that most people will be looking for, altering data in persistent tables, the short answer is **No**, and reference @Dan's answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35753050)